# Wrong Flash in Odin

Tags: unbricking, samsung-galaxy-j1

My question is I accidentally put the firmware in BL and AP in Odin My phone is Samsung J1. It says success but my phone is like having dead battery and I cant open it . the (power button + volume down + home button) download screen didn't appear whenever I tried to access. what to do ?

Comment: Please specify which file you used.

Comment: in the firmware , there is a file with and extension of BL and another file with an Extension of AP. 
I put them together in AP and BL slot in Odin at the same time. and that's what happened

Comment: I mean, what file you actually used for flashing? Where did you get it?

Comment: https://samdb.org/download/GALAXY__J1__/1z34/GLB/J100MLDXU0AOC1/J100MLOLC0AOC1/
here
It worked on my first time and btw it's my second time around . 
on my first, I only used AP but on my second time, I accidentally put BL and AP together .

Comment: Have you tried again? for the 3rd time?

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat late answer, but it could warn others even if it is too late to help OP.

BL is the bootloader partition, which is the first software that loads when you power on your device, before even the Download and Recovery modes. It looks like you flashed a wrong file for the bootloader, and if that is the case unfortunately your phone will not boot again unless you swap out the whole eMMC. (Internal Storage) You could try taking it for an authorized Samsung repair store as they might have debug software but I highly doubt they could interact with the hardware which comes before the bootloader.

*TL;DR: Odin is an extremely powerful tool, and even though OP's device is not very expensive, use it with extreme care or you may end up with a paperweight worth $1200.*